# Unexpected Behavior from a Linq Contains() Method

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, contains

In a filter of customers, this statement returns all customers with any part of the `selectedIDs` in their `CustomerID`.

For example, `selectedIDs` value '1' returns `CustomerID` '1' and '10'...

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedIDs) && selectedIDs != "*")
{
    query = query.Where(x => selectedIDs.Contains(x.CustomerID.ToString()));
}
```

How can I get this query to only return customers with the full `selectedIDs`?

Comment: how are the IDs separated in the string ?

Comment: not 'unexpected', because the string "10" does contain "1"

Comment: FYI, `Contains` is not a "LINQ" method

Comment: @rob you have the container-containee relationship reversed based on what OP is saying, though it makes sense in the case that selectedIDs=10 and CustomerID=1.

Comment: selectedIDs are separated like '1,2,3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the Linq Contains method here... you're using the string.Contains method.... You need to split the string using the delineating character and go from there.

```
var trueSelectedIds = selectedIDs.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
query = query.Where(x => trueSelectedIds.Contains(x.CustomerID.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks very much guys for providing several great solutions to my problem so quickly. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
query = query.Where(x => selectedIDs.Split(',')
                              .Contains(x.CustomerID.ToString()));
```

Comment: The @David Morton answer is preferred.

Comment: While this is briefer, it's less performant.  This technique will split the string every time the delegate passed into "Where" is run.

Nevertheless, it shouldn't matter too much if there aren't that many items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `CustomerID` is an `int`, put the following in your `if` block:

```
var realSelectedIDs = new HashSet(
    selectedIDs.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)));
query = query.Where(x => realSelectedIDs.Contains(x.CustomerID));
```

A `HashSet` gives you an `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` lookup.

(You might want to get use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to protect against bad input, or you might not care. You could just as well drop the `int.Parse` and use `x.CustomerID.ToString()` as before.)

Comment: And what about overhead of hashing?

Comment: @Hamlet Although of course I'd advocate actually mesuring alternatives in real use cases and picking whicever was generally faster, I'd use a `HashSet` over an array by default to do a `Contains` check any day. Hash once or iterate multiple times? I'd go with hash.

Comment: Even on days where the array contains one element?  ;)

Comment: @KennethK. If that's a common use case it'd show up under "actually measuring" :p